# simple, fast, easy to use photo Croping software

Tags: windows, image-processing

I have a lot of photos. Eash Photo should be Cropped. Photos aren't 'same': different sizes,different angles,etc.So each photo should be cropped bu me manually,by selecting a rectangle.is there a Software that allows to :

1. Open a folder with pictures.
2. Automatically open first of them.
3. Crop a Picture by selecting a rectangle.
4. Save Cropped image and automatically go to the next.

Comment: Must it be [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget?